# Magento - Determine what pages is available to handle

Tags: magento-1.9, module, product-page

how can i determine what pages is available to handle in magento layout files? after default handle (which shows up on almost every page) there're few handles for example :

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
........
</checkout_cart_index>
```

which goes to the checkout cart page.

while the file in app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/ contains .phtml for function in each block, how can i know where is the list of php page for the website?

from what i studied at magento Designer guide PDF i only knows that handle itself shows what pages it should show the module inside, which is there's default, or other specific pages we want to show, but i can't understand how can i get the list of pages and what is the tag ex : **

For instance, `<catalog_product_view>` contains the layout updates for
 the Product View page, while `<catalog_product_compare_index>` contains
those for the Compare Product page.

this is taken from the pdf itself which is the tag is not the same as the page name also. i'm getting a bit confused here, i have read all of the pdf about the block, the attributes of the block, customizing template module etc and this is the only thing i haven't understand.

Comment: do you want to know the list of handlers available in magento ?

Comment: @Ashish Madankar yes i guess that's what i want to know, since it isn't listed in the pdf designer guide. isn't handler the same as page it will be shown at anyway? am i mistaken?

Comment: Their is no known reference which provide list of handlers but at http://snipplr.com/view/61215/log-down-all-loaded-layout-handles-in-magento-on-each-request/ you will get a list of handlers for a request. as well as if you want to know the name of handler for a particular   page then you can find it easily form class name in body tag of the page. in magento handler of a page is available in the body tag for ex: for home page it will show as cms-index-index so the handler name will be cms_index_index  just replace - with _ hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

usually the layout handle matches the url.
If the url is `module/controller/action` the layout handle would be `module_controller_action`.
If the url is `module/controller` (the action is missing) then the action defaults to `index`. So the handle would be `module_controller_index`.
If both controller and action are missing then the layout handle would be `module_index_index`.

if any of the parts in the url contains an underscore this one will be kept in the handle.
So for `module/some_controller/action` you get `module_some_controller_action`.

These are the general handles.
But there are a few special handles that are loaded for special occasions.
I don't have a full list, but here are some examples:

- `customer_logged_in` - loaded for all pages when the customer is logged in
- `customer_logged_out` - loaded for all the pages when the customer is not logged in.
- `catalog_category_layered` - loaded for categories with `is_anchor` set to `yes`.
- `catalog_category_default` - loaded for categories with `is_anchor` set to `no`.
- `cms_index_index` - for homepage.
- `cms_page` loaded for all cms pages.
- `PRODUCT_TYPE_simple` - for all simple products (there is one similar for configurable, virtual, ...).
- `CATEGORY_5` - loaded for category with id 5.